# zope interface verifyObject() не замечает self атрибута в классе

Tags: python, интерфейс

В документации говорится, что:

Attributes of the object, be they defined by its class or added by its `__init__` method, will be recognized:

```
>>> from zope.interface import Interface, Attribute, implementer
>>> from zope.interface import Invalid
>>> from zope.interface.verify import verifyObject
>>> oname, __name__ = __name__, 'base' # Pretend we're in a module, not a doctest
>>> class IBase(Interface):
...     x = Attribute("The X attribute")
>>> __name__ = 'module' # Pretend to be a different module.

>>> class IFoo(IBase):
...     y = Attribute("The Y attribute")
>>> __name__ = oname; del oname

>>> @implementer(IFoo)
... class Foo(object):
...     x = 1
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.y = 2

>>> verifyObject(IFoo, Foo())
True
```

Я пытаюсь повторить то же самое, только с другим кодом:

```
import zope.interface
from zope.interface.verify import verifyObject

class IPerson(zope.interface.Interface):
    _name = zope.interface.Attribute('Name')
    _surname = zope.interface.Attribute('Surname')
    _age = zope.interface.Attribute('Age')

@zope.interface.implementer(IPerson)
class Test:
    _surname = ""

    def __init__(self):
        self._name = ""
        self._age = ""


verifyObject(IPerson, Test)
```

И у меня возникает ошибка, что не все атрибуты реализованы. По сути проверка замечает только поле класса

```
zope.interface.exceptions.MultipleInvalid: The object <class 'models.Test'> has failed to implement interface models.IPerson:
Does not declaratively implement the interface
The models.IPerson.Name attribute was not provided
The models.IPerson.Age attribute was not provided
```

Что я делаю не так, подскажите, пожалуйста

Comment: Решил проблему. Как всегда, дело в мелочах. В verifyObject(IPerson, Test), нужно было добавить скобки к Test, чтобы получилось verifyObject(IPerson, Test())

Comment: А, ну логично, если должен проверяться экземпляр класса, а не сам класс

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, была похожая проблема, если забыть скобки, то параметр будет сам класс, а не его экземпляр.

То есть, такая разница:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     x = 1

>>> Foo
<class '__main__.Foo'>
>>> Foo()
<__main__.Foo object at 0x6fffffdde5c0>
```